# Wait method suggestion on page fully loaded

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Before input the value we are using wait method until DOM load,if i used webdriver wait im getting stale element error message ,what is the best approach to use wait method where we require page to load DOM elements

```
public static void waitForPageToComplete(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, ofSeconds(2));
        wait.until(pageLoad);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Wait for page to load" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about how it is on java, but checking `document.readyState` in selenium python often doesn't work.